# Finding False-True and True-True row indices

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy boolean vector (taken from a pandas dataframe) called `data['3_changed']`.  I can find the indices of all values marked `True` by simply entering:

```
In [106]: np.where(data['3_changed'])
Out[106]: (array([    37,     41,     83, ..., 998011, 998019, 998025]),)
```

Now I would like to

1. access the row immediately preceding `True` values
2. if that value is `False`, get that row's index as well

I have tried

`np.where(data['3_changed'].diff())`

However, this returns rows that have a `False-True` grouping, and excludes rows that are `True-True`.  For example, rows 997932 and 997933 would be excluded below.

```
997928    False
997929    False
997930    False
997931    False
997932     True
997933     True
997934    False
997935    False
997936    False
997937    False
997938    False
997939    False
997940    False
997941    False
997942     True
```

Is there a way to efficiently iterate over my DataFrame `data` and perform this check with some kind of `if` statement?

Comment: Can't you just loop through the list and [logical_or](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html#numpy.logical_or) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand you, and you're looking for the indices where either the element is True or the next element is True, you can take advantage of `shift` and use

```
s.index[s | s.shift(-1)]
```

For example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True])
>>> s
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
>>> s | s.shift(-1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
>>> s.index[s | s.shift(-1)]
Int64Index([1, 2, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: apologies for the delayed response, got pulled into a meeting.  this is indeed what I'm looking for, I will research the `shift()` method more.

Answer (score 0):

If your Boolean array is called `a`, you can use

```
a | numpy.r_[a[1:], False]
```

to get an array that is `True` at some index whenever the original array is `True` at that index or the following one.  Now you can use `numpy.where()` on this neww array to retrieve all the desired indices.

Example:

```
> a = numpy.array([False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False])
> a | numpy.r_[a[1:], False]
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `shift(distance)` you compare two rows:

```
data = '''idx  a
997928    False
997929    False
997930    False
997931    False
997932     True
997933     True
997934    False
997935    False
997936    False
997937    False
997938    False
997939    False
997940    False
997941    False
997942     True'''

import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv( StringIO(data), sep='\s+' )

#df['b'] = df['a'].shift(-1)

print df

print df[ (df['a'] == False) & (df['a'].shift(-1) == True) ]
```

result

```
            a
idx          
997931  False
997941  False
```

Then you can use `.index` to get only `indexes`

```
print df[ (df['a'] == False) & (df['a'].shift(-1) == True) ].index
```

---

BTW: You can add `df['b'] = df['a'].shift(-1)` to see compared values

```
            a      b
idx                 
997928  False  False
997929  False  False
997930  False  False
997931  False   True
997932   True   True
997933   True  False
997934  False  False
997935  False  False
997936  False  False
997937  False  False
997938  False  False
997939  False  False
997940  False  False
997941  False   True
997942   True    NaN
```